# Choosing the row with the most recent change in a value

Tags: sql, row, proc-sql

I want to be able to select the most recent row with a change in any column value from the previous row.

For example, in this table, there is a change from Jan1 to Jan3 in the indicator value so we would move to Jan2. Subsequently there is a change in rate on Jan9, so we would move to Jan9 and the final output would be the Jan9 row since that was the row with the most recent change.

```
date rate    indicator
Jan1 2.00    Y  
Jan3 2.00    N  
Jan9 3.00    N
```

In this table, there is a change in indicator from Jan1 to Jan3 but no subsequent change in any values on Jan9. Therefore the output row would be the Jan3 row.

```
date rate    indicator
Jan1 2.00    Y  
Jan3 2.00    N  
Jan9 2.00    N
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and then ordering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (order by date) as prev_date,
             lag(date) over (partition by rate, indicator order by date) as prev_ri_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_ri_date <> prev_date or prev_ri_date is null  -- aha!  something changed
order by date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in SAS using proc sql and it doesn't seem to be identifying the lag over portion

Comment: @schan . . . Your question was not tagged as "SAS" in any way.  This answer is standard SQL, and `proc sql` will support it in pass-thru queries.  SAS doesn't offer native support for window functions.  You can use a data step with `retain`.